# How I can get all combinations that have duplicates in Java (recursion)?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion, duplicates

I need to find a way to remove duplicates from a combination like this:

*Input:* 3 and 2, where 3 is the range (from 1 to 3) and 2 is the length of each combination

*Output*: `{1, 1} {1, 2} {1, 3} {2, 1} {2, 2} {2, 3} {3, 1} {3, 2} {3, 3}`

*Expected output*: `{1, 1} {1, 2} {1, 3} {2, 2} {2, 3} {3, 3}`

So we start with `{1, 1} -> {1, 2} -> {1, 3} ->` but `{2, 1}` is a duplicate of `{1, 2}` so we ignore it and so on.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static int[] result;
    private static int n;

    private static void printArray() {
        String str = "( ";
        for (int number : result) {
            str += number + " ";
        }
        System.out.print(str + ") ");
    }

    private static void gen(int index) {
        if (index == result.length) {
            printArray();
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            result[index] = i;
            gen(index + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("From 1 to: ");
        n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Length: ");
        int k = input.nextInt();

        result = new int[k];

        gen(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations_with_repetitions#Java

Comment: What you're looking for is combinations in the combinatorics sense of the word.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination Much code already exists for this https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=combinatorics%20combinations%20java

Comment: Why don't you create a hash of every entry? The hashing function should take care of cases like {1,2} and {2,1} and you'll also overcome the searching for duplicates because the hashing function would be making sure that it prints OR stores the duplicates somewhere.

Comment: You can map this {1,2} entry to a POJO and your hash function should take a POJO and return the hash as well as telling duplicates (using a static function that matches 2 objs)

Hash can be string concatenation OR an add function because u can have only 1, 2, 3 as inputs so you won't get the case where {1, 4} and {2,3} get equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the last max value used into `gen`:

```
private static void gen(int index, int minI) {
    if (index == result.length) {
        printArray();
        return;
    }
    for (int i = minI; i <= n; i++) {
        result[index] = i;
        gen(index + 1, i);
    }
}
```

And call it starting with `1`: `gen(0, 1);`