# Combinations Java

Tags: java, duplicates, combinations

I need a combination function which return also duplicate of himself:

i tried to modify this function but i didnt succeed :

```
public static Set<List<Integer>> combinationsListInteger(List<Integer> groupSize, int k) {

    Set<List<Integer>> allCombos = new HashSet<List<Integer>> ();
    // base cases for recursion
    if (k == 0) {
        // There is only one combination of size 0, the empty team.
        allCombos.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        return allCombos;
    }
    if (k > groupSize.size()) {
        // There can be no teams with size larger than the group size,
        // so return allCombos without putting any teams in it.
        return allCombos;
    }

    // Create a copy of the group with one item removed.
    List<Integer> groupWithoutX = new ArrayList<Integer> (groupSize);
    Integer x = groupWithoutX.remove(groupWithoutX.size()-1);

    Set<List<Integer>> combosWithoutX = combinationsListInteger(groupWithoutX, k);
    Set<List<Integer>> combosWithX = combinationsListInteger(groupWithoutX, k-1);
    for (List<Integer> combo : combosWithX) {
        combo.add(x);
    }
    allCombos.addAll(combosWithoutX);
    allCombos.addAll(combosWithX);
    return allCombos;
}
```

When i call it with : 
    `combinationsListIntegerAll([1,2,3],3)`

it returns only : `[1,2,3]`

What i want is :

```
[1,1,1]
[1,1,2]
[1,1,3]
[1,2,3]
[2,1,1]
[2,1,2]
[2,1,3]
[2,2,2]
[2,2,3]...
```

Is someone have an idea? Thanks you to much

Comment: So, you want to do all combinations  of those numbers. Shouldn't be there `[1, 2, 1]` or I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: yes sorry i forgot it , finally after multiple research i found a way in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535327/how-i-can-get-all-combinations-that-have-duplicates-in-java-recursion